# Getting device location without displayin blue dot on monotouch

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, mkmapview

Some times it need that you set the center of map in user current location but not showing the blue dot.Suppose that you just want to have the area, but you don't want that user concentrate on his location on map. You want to them concentrate on the other objects of map.

How we can get user location but not showing  the blue dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the location with

```
mapView.userLocation
```

So, to set the `mapView`'s center with it:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=0.02 / 10; // zoom level
span.longitudeDelta=0.02 / 10; 

CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
location.longitude = mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;

region.span=span;
region.center=location; 

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];
```

Then, you can hide the blue dot with:

```
[mapView setShowUserLocation:NO];
```

Not sure what the actual MonoTouch equivalent to this Objective-C code is, but it should be named similarly.

Answer (score 5):

Monotouch equivalent of Tim's answer is:

```
mapView .ShowsUserLocation =true ;
        mapView.DidUpdateUserLocation += (sender, e) => {
            if (mapView.UserLocation != null) {
                CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
                location.Latitude  = mapView.UserLocation .Coordinate .Latitude ;
                location.Longitude  = mapView.UserLocation .Coordinate.Longitude;
                mapView .CenterCoordinate =location ;
                mapView .ShowsUserLocation =false ;

            }
        };
```